# SwiftUI macOS searchable keyboard navigation

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, searchable

Having search suggestion

```
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar) {
            List {
                Text("Search suggestion 1").searchCompletion("Hello")
                Text("Search suggestion 2").searchCompletion("Hello 2")
            }.listStyle(.sidebar)
        }
```

How to enable keyboard Up/Down navigation between suggestion like in Finder

Even the mouse selection doesn't do anything

[image]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key was to use `Section` and `Labels` with the .`searchCompletion`, all works great (keyboard, completion...)

the results can also be calculated on the flight as demonstrated

```
    .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar) {
        if searchText.count == 0 {
            Section("Fonts") {
                Label("Font family A", systemImage: "textformat").searchCompletion("familyA")
                Label("Font family B", systemImage: "textformat").searchCompletion("familyB")
            }
            Divider()
            Section("Foundries") {
                Label("Foundry A", systemImage: "briefcase").searchCompletion("foundry:A")
                Label("Foundry B", systemImage: "briefcase").searchCompletion("foundry:B")
            }
            Divider()
            Section("Designers") {
                Label("Author 1", systemImage: "person").searchCompletion("author:A")
                Label("Author 2", systemImage: "person").searchCompletion("author:B")
            }
            Divider()
            Section("Keywords") {
                Label("Keyword 1", systemImage: "tag").searchCompletion("tag:A")
                Label("Keyword 2", systemImage: "tag").searchCompletion("tag:B")
            }
            Divider()
            Section("Letters") {
                Label("N", systemImage: "textformat.size.larger").searchCompletion("letter:A")
            }
        } else {
            Section("Keywords") {
                Text("X").searchCompletion("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]